# Android, C#: Alpha Animation only works when inital alpha is at 1. Cannot start from 0?

Tags: c#, android

In my app, I want an image button to change its alpha with an animation. 
The alpha of the imagebutton is in `oncreate` 0. It is invisible. Now, when I click on a certain button and just go:

```
Onclick
{
    mybutton.Alpha = 1f;
};
```

Then it changes my buttons alpha to 1. Ergo the button is visible.

I now decided, I dont want the button to simply go from 0 to 1 in one frame, but instead id like it animated. Say in wihtin 1 second from 0 to 1. So i wrote this function:

```
private void AnimForBtnAwesome(float intAnimateToAlpha)
{
    AlphaAnimation animation = null;
    animation = new AlphaAnimation(0, intAnimateToAlpha);
    animation.FillAfter = true;
    animation.SetInterpolator(this, Android.Resource.Animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator);
    animation.Duration = 1000;
    btnAwesome.StartAnimation(animation);
}
```

This function does **nothing** unless the initial alpha for my button is set to 1 (in `oncreate`).
But I want my button to be invisible until a certain button is clicked (`onclick` above).

When I set my initial alpha for said button to 1 in `oncreate` and the animation starts, it basically vanishes for a frame and then fades in back to where it just been one second ago. This is pretty stupid and seems like an easy fix. Yet I haven't been able to find out why this is and how to bypass it. Maybe there is another way of hiding a button without adjusting the alpha? Though this seems like too much of a hassle. Why not just have it change its initial alpha value to 1 via animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding an AnimationListener to your alpha animation. On animation start set the button visibility to visible, at this point you should be able to see the alpha changing also when the initial alpha is 0.

If you want on animation end you can set the view's visibility as you prefer.

Comment: perfect.To those wondering:I added this line: btnAwesome.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;